# Codeigniter site working in MAMP but not LAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp, lamp

I am using MAMP to locally host my codeigniter project.  Each of my controllers extends MY_Controller.  MY_Controller looks like the following:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
          parent::__construct();

          $this->load->model('user_model');
          $this->user_model->do_something();
    }
}
```

Using MAMP, on my macbook, this works fine.  However, when I upload my site to my linux server running apache, I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: User_model
```

Why?

UPDATE

I changed the capitalization to be like this:

```
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->do_something();
```

and the problem continues

Comment: Try to change the name of your model file to fit capitalization in message.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is a case-sensitive operating system, and as such you need to be really careful when developing on Windows and deploying to Linux.

Your issue stems from the line :

```
$this->user_model->do_something();
```

Which should be :

```
$this->User_model->do_something();
```

As it is the name of an object you are trying to access.

The line which loads it is fine, as CodeIgniter doesn't mind which case you use to load the models, but PHP will get somewhat picky on Linux when it comes to names of things.

Comment: I changed the capitalization and the problem continues.  It works on my mac running MAMP, but it gives me the same error message in linux.